# how to solve Internal Server Error in spring data

Tags: spring

Hello I want to update this entity, but I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXFrH.png)

Thanks for your help!

```java
@PostMapping("updateabitre/{id}")
public Arbitre updateArbitre(@PathVariable Long id, Arbitre newArbitre){
    ServiceArbitre serviceArbitre = null;
    Arbitre arbitre = serviceArbitre.getArbitreById(id);
    arbitre.setNomArbitre(newArbitre.getNomArbitre());
    arbitre.setNationnalite(newArbitre.getNationnalite());

    serviceArbitre.updateArbitre(arbitre);
    return arbitre;
}
```

Comment: fix the root cause!;) `ServiceArbitre serviceArbitre = null;Arbitre arbitre = serviceArbitre.getArbitreById(id);` ("guaranteed" null-pointer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are setting `serviceArbitre` to `null` before immediately invoking one of its functions, hence the `NullPointerException`.

```java
ServiceArbitre serviceArbitre = null;
Arbitre arbitre = serviceArbitre.getArbitreById(id);
```

Also, you may need to annotate updated entity parameter (`Arbitre newArbitre`) with `@RequestBody`, that is:

```java
public Arbitre updateArbitre(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Arbitre newArbitre){
```

Otherwise Spring may not know to map the HTTP request body to the object.